# Parsing XML Failed

Tags: java, xml, soap-client

I get the following response XML String after calling a SOAP web service. How can i parse the response back to Java entity so that i can handle the `ErrMsg` and `Status` accordingly? I tried with the below code, but keep getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"NewDataSet"). Expected elements are <{TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs}NewDataSet>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
```

**Sample Response in String**

```
 <NewDataSet>
  <SubmissionResult>
    <Status>200</Status>
    <RefNo>363180319bigKj83i</RefNo>
    <ErrMsg>Successful</ErrMsg>
  </SubmissionResult>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Sample Client XML Parser**

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NewDataSet.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    StringReader reader = new StringReader("Sample Response in String above");
    NewDataSet newDataSet = (NewDataSet) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    System.out.println(newDataSet.getSubmissionResult());
```

**NewDataSet.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
 "submissionResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "NewDataSet")
public class NewDataSet {

 @XmlElement(name = "SubmissionResult", required = true)
 protected NewDataSet.SubmissionResult submissionResult;

 public NewDataSet.SubmissionResult getSubmissionResult() {
  return submissionResult;
 }

 public void setSubmissionResult(NewDataSet.SubmissionResult value) {
  this.submissionResult = value;
 }

 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "status",
  "refNo",
  "errMsg"
 })
 public static class SubmissionResult {

  @XmlElement(name = "Status")
  protected short status;
  @XmlElement(name = "RefNo", required = true)
  protected String refNo;
  @XmlElement(name = "ErrMsg", required = true)
  protected String errMsg;

  public short getStatus() {
   return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(short value) {
   this.status = value;
  }

  public String getRefNo() {
   return refNo;
  }

  public void setRefNo(String value) {
   this.refNo = value;
  }

  public String getErrMsg() {
   return errMsg;
  }

  public void setErrMsg(String value) {
   this.errMsg = value;
  }
 }

}
```

Note: If possible i prefer to use standard java library or external library that is being maintained regularly and up to date.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others. For some reason you have a namespace "TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs" in there, even though it's not visible why.

Comment: noted on this. Will improve the way i ask questions next time. Anyway how can i find out where there is a namespace there?

Comment: If you don't know where this namespace come from you can do a project wide text search of your program code for "TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs" and/or check the contents of your XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason, it was resolved by removing the `namespace = "TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs"`

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs",elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mailadapter;
```

to become

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mailadapter;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have many `NewDataSet` classes in your `POJO` model. Check this line of code `JAXBContext.newInstance(NewDataSet.class)` and check `import` whether you imported correct one because exception says that marshaller expects `TransactionalSubmissionsSvcs.NewDataSet`.

### Before edit

You did not mention what the tool do you use. In case it is [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) you can parse `XML` payload as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "your xml";

        parse(xml);
    }

    public static void parse(String xml) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        JsonNode root = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
        JsonNode result = root.at("/SendWithXMLResult");
        JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(result.asText());
        JsonNode submissionResult = jsonNode.at("/SubmissionResult");

        System.out.println(submissionResult.get("Status"));
        System.out.println(submissionResult.get("ErrMsg"));
        System.out.println(submissionResult.get("RefNo"));
    }
}
```

If you have prepared `POJO` model you can deserialise `XML` directly to it using `readValue` method.

Comment: So sorry Michal Ziober, i have posted my question incorrectly Before that due to my mistake. I have edited again.

Comment: @Phua, please see my update. How many `NewDataSet` classes do you have in your model?